# What is the Featured Image area for on the TwentyTen theme using WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, upload, themes, twenty-ten-theme

I am creating a child theme in Wordpress using the TwentyTen theme as a parent. I saw under the Pages area in the admin section, there is a 'Featured Image' area, but I don't see where that featured image is shown on the page.

What is the featured image area for? I would ideally like to use that uploader to put an image at a specified location on the page.

In what file for twentyten can I find the code php code for the Featured Image area that is displayed in the pages admin area? I looked all through the functions.php file. I'm guessing it is a function in the core files and it is being called in the functions.php file in the twentyten theme, but I can't seem to see where that is happening. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Featured Image* is sometimes called the *Post Thumbnail*. Where this shows up depends on your theme, but [for TwentyTen, it replaces the default header image](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-thumbnail-amp-twenty-ten-theme). You can see the code in use in [`header.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-content/themes/twentyten/header.php#L68):

```
<?php
// Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
if ( is_singular() &&
        has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
        ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' ) ) &&
        $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
    // Houston, we have a new header image!
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
else : ?>
    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
<?php endif; ?>
```